# Branching from $E(6)$ to $SO(10) \times U(1)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-groups, mp.mathematical-physics, supersymmetry

In $E(6)$ inspired models of supersymmetry, the inclusion of Lie subgroups 
$$
SO(10) \times U(1) \hookrightarrow E_6
$$
is important object of interest. See [here](http://inspirehep.net/record/1116270/files/arXiv%3A1205.5967.pdf) for my motivating example.

In particular, paper uses the decomposition of some irreducible representations of $E(6)$ into its irreducible sub-representations with respect to the subgroup $SO(10) \times U(1)$.

Such rules as these are called "branching rules". Does there exist a single  branching rule of the general $E(6)$ irreducible representation to its irreducible $SO(10) \times U(1)$-irreducible subrepresentations? What is a best reference?

Comment: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/sla/doc/chap5.html

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littelmann_path_model#Branching_rule.  You're branching to a Levi subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following reference will be useful: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370157381900922 (Group theory for unified model building, by R.Slansky).